# Spring security custom FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource implementation 403 forbidden issue

Tags: authentication, spring-security, authorization, http-status-code-403, access-denied

To make things short I'm trying to implement a custom FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource in order to secure/authorize certain parts/URL endpoints dynamically in my web app using spring security 5.0.6 and Spring Boot 2.0.3.

The issue is that no matter what Role I use it always gives me the forbidden page.

I have tried several things with different role names and (believe me) I have searched the whole internet even on spring security 5.0.6 books but nothing seems to work.

This issue may be similar to this: [Spring Security issue with securing URLs dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48635647/spring-security-issue-with-securing-urls-dynamically)

Below the relevant parts of the custom FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource

```
public class DbFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource implements FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource {

public Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object)
        throws IllegalArgumentException {
    FilterInvocation fi=(FilterInvocation)object;
    String url=fi.getRequestUrl();

    System.out.println("URL requested: " + url);

    String[] stockArr = new String[]{"ROLE_ADMIN"};

    return SecurityConfig.createList(stockArr);
}
```

Below the relevant parts of the custom implementation of securitywebconfigAdapter

```
@Configuration
public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .withObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<FilterSecurityInterceptor>() {
            public <O extends FilterSecurityInterceptor> O postProcess(
                    O fsi) {
                FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource newSource = new DbFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource();
                fsi.setSecurityMetadataSource(newSource);
                return fsi;
            }
        })
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .permitAll();
}
```

Below the relevant parts for custom userDetails authorities.
The user has the role: ROLE_ADMIN in database.

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    List<String> dbRoles=new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Role userRole : super.getRoles()) {
        dbRoles.add(userRole.getType());
    }

    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities=new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
    for (String role : dbRoles) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
    return authorities;
}
```

What am I doing wrong??
If more code is needed just comment below.
If you have even good books where I can learn this dynamic part of Spring security authorization comment below.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get into the security flow by debugging and it seems that by creating ConfigAttributes of this SecurityConfig class is the 'culprit'

```
return SecurityConfig.createList(stockArr);
public static List<ConfigAttribute> createList(String... attributeNames) {
    Assert.notNull(attributeNames, "You must supply an array of attribute names");
    List<ConfigAttribute> attributes = new ArrayList(attributeNames.length);
    String[] var2 = attributeNames;
    int var3 = attributeNames.length;

    for(int var4 = 0; var4 < var3; ++var4) {
        String attribute = var2[var4];
        attributes.add(new SecurityConfig(attribute.trim()));
    }

    return attributes;
}
```

Above is the actual implementation of the method where you can see

```
attributes.add(new SecurityConfig(attribute.trim()));
```

And this always creates an instance of SecurityConfig type.

And below you can actually see where and how the decision is being made.

```
private WebExpressionConfigAttribute findConfigAttribute(Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
    Iterator var2 = attributes.iterator();

    ConfigAttribute attribute;
    do {
        if (!var2.hasNext()) {
            return null;
        }

        attribute = (ConfigAttribute)var2.next();
    } while(!(attribute instanceof WebExpressionConfigAttribute));

    return (WebExpressionConfigAttribute)attribute;
}
```

So in order for it to actually return a configattribute for checking it must be of type WebExpressionConfigAttribute which is never going to be the case because of this

```
attributes.add(new SecurityConfig(attribute.trim()));
```

So the way I fixed it is to create my own accessDecisionManager the following way

```
public class MyAccessDecisionManager implements AccessDecisionManager {
@Override
public void decide(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes)
        throws AccessDeniedException, InsufficientAuthenticationException {
    if(configAttributes == null){
        return  ;
    }
    Iterator<ConfigAttribute> ite = configAttributes.iterator();
    while(ite.hasNext()){

        ConfigAttribute ca = ite.next();

        String needRole = ((SecurityConfig)ca).getAttribute();

        for(GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authentication.getAuthorities()){
            if(needRole.trim().equals(grantedAuthority.getAuthority().trim())){
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    throw new AccessDeniedException("Access is denied");
}
```

And registering as above now setting the accessdecisionManager with my custom one

```
.withObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<FilterSecurityInterceptor>() {
        public <O extends FilterSecurityInterceptor> O postProcess(
                O fsi) {
            FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource newSource = new DbFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource();
            fsi.setSecurityMetadataSource(newSource);
            fsi.setAccessDecisionManager(new MyAccessDecisionManager());
            return fsi;
        }
```